# Android- RecyclerView Adapter - How to implement endless scrolling without deleting previous items

Tags: scroll, adapter, android-recyclerview, infinite

I'm developing an app to get tweets and display them on screen.
I've user RecyclerView and it works fine.

The thing is that when I get to the last item, I'm swapping the adapter in order to get new items, but the previous items get deleted and I can't scroll back to view them.

```
recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter,true);
```

How can I implement endless scrolling without losing my previous values ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/

All I've had to do is add items to the list of items that's already in the adapter and then use "notifyItemInserted(position)".

Same idea for removal.